# How can i use infinite scroll plugin with this code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

My code works correctly for showing database data .but i want to use infinite scroll for large data show response time.But I have no Idea how to use infinite scroll with my this code also which plugin use.

```
<script>
    function getfilter(str){
        if (str==""){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "Views/pfolioresult.php?q="+str,
            type: "GET",
            //  data: serializedData,
            success: function ( responseText ) {
                $("#result").html(responseText); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="sprocket-mosaic-header">
    <div class="sprocket-mosaic-filter">
        <ul>
            <li class="all active" data-mosaic-filterby="all" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="all" >All</li>
            <li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="android" >Android</li>
            <li class="iOS" data-mosaic-filterby="iOS" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="ios" >IOS</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div id="result">
    ok
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/ or http://jscroll.com/. this will help you.

Comment: My words precisely. @shanto, I think you should read the instructions before asking people to do your homework. Here is another one: [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).